# Too many redirects - Owin External Login with Facebook Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm creating a web-api where I need to log people in using Facebook.

I'm following [this guide](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/).

Once I provide my credentials to Facebook, it should redirect to an Action but instead it says: "Too many redirects." 
[image]

This is what I've got in my *Startup.cs*:

```
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            FacebookAuthenticationOptions facebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "myAppId",
                AppSecret = "myAppKey",
                Provider = new FacebookAuthProvider()
            };
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthOptions);
```

This is my *FacebookAuthProvider*: class:

```
public class FacebookAuthProvider : FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public override Task Authenticated(FacebookAuthenticatedContext context)
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("ExternalAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

This is my *ChallengeResult* class:

```
public class ChallengeResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public ChallengeResult(string loginProvider, ApiController controller)
        {
            LoginProvider = loginProvider;
            Request = controller.Request;
        }
        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(LoginProvider);

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response);
        }
    }
```

And this is the controller that I'm using to get the token from Facebook after user has logged in:

```
[HttpGet]
        [OverrideAuthentication]
        [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        //[Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetExternalLogin(string provider)
        {
            string redirectUri = string.Empty;
            AppUserManager manager = new AppUserManager(new AppUserStore(new AppContext()));

            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
            }

            ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

            UserLoginInfo loginInfo = new UserLoginInfo(externalLogin.LoginProvider, externalLogin.ProviderKey);

            IdentityUser user = manager.Find(loginInfo);

            bool hasRegistered = user != null;

            ValidateRedirectUri(this.Request, ref redirectUri);

            redirectUri = String.Format("{0}#external_access_token={1}&provider={2}&haslocalaccount={3}&external_user_name={4}",
                                            redirectUri,
                                            externalLogin.AccessToken,
                                            externalLogin.LoginProvider,
                                            hasRegistered.ToString(),
                                            externalLogin.UserName);

            return Redirect(redirectUri);
        }
```

One thing that I'm really curious about, is that, if I uncomment this line:

```
[Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
```

And try to access that controller with that new route, it says that `User` (The one in the GetExternalLogin's if) is `null`.

This is the link that I'm using to test:
`http://localhost:62887/api/ExternalAuth/GetExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&redirect_uri=http://localhost:62887/api/ExternalAuth/LoggedIn`

And after the user has successfully logged in, this is the action that he's supposed to be redirected:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult LoggedIn()
        {
            return Ok(new { Message = "You've been successfully logged in! :)" });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna kill myself, I finally got it working. I just had to update the NuGet Package from 2.1 to 3.1... >:/

Comment: Hey are you still alive

Comment: Yup, what's up?